# What does the system_cpu_usage metric mean and how to convert it to a percentage?

Tags: prometheus, micronaut

My PrometheusMeterRegistry returns a very low decimal value for the system_cpu_usage metric (0.004593000743494424). I want to display this value in a Grafana dashboard as a percentage of the overall CPU usage. I can't find much about this metric in the Micronaut documentation and I don't want to make assumptions about what this metric means.

Which unit is this metric in and how could I convert this to a percentage value (from 0% to 100%)?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923788/prometheus-convert-cpu-user-seconds-to-cpu-usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus. CPU process time total to % percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384757/prometheus-cpu-process-time-total-to-percent)

Comment: Thanks @jeff-scott-brown , I know how to convert CPU seconds to a percentage, but I am specifically referring to Micronaut's `system_cpu_usage` metric.

Comment: Apologies.  I thought they were the same.